# Laravel + Vue Lang.js Localization

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Estou tendo dificuldades em traduzir minha página usando o **Lang.js** no **Laravel**.

Preciso pegar a linguagem escolhida nas configurações do usuário usando o **Axios**, e traduzir usando um filtro do **Vue**.

A função responsável por coletar a linguagem escolhida pelo usuário é a `getLanguage()`, que se encontra no `created hook`.

Depois de coletar os dados, eu salvo no `config.linguagem` e então eu altero a linguagem utilizando o `Lang.setLocale()`.

Porém, quando eu verifico via console a linguagem escolhida, na `mounted hook`, ele escolhe a linguagem padrão **"en"**, como se eu não tivesse setado a linguagem do usuário.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

```
    <template>
    <table class="display table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>{{ 'cptasks.gerentes.nome' | trans }}</th>
                <th>{{ 'cptasks.gerentes.email' | trans }}</th>
                <th>{{ 'cptasks.gerentes.categoria' | trans }}</th>
                <th>{{ 'cptasks.gerentes.opcoes' | trans }}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
               <th colspan="5">...</th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>{{ 'cptasks.gerentes.nome' | trans }}</th>
                <th>{{ 'cptasks.gerentes.email' | trans }}</th>
                <th>{{ 'cptasks.gerentes.categoria' | trans }}</th>
                <th>{{ 'cptasks.gerentes.opcoes' | trans }}</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</template>

<script>
    import Lang from '../lang.js';

    export default {
        data(){
            return{
                usuarios: [],
                config: {
                  linguagem: null,
                }
            }
        },
        created(){
            this.getLanguage();
        },
        mounted () {
            console.log(Lang.getLocale());
        },
        methods: {
            getLanguage(){
                var vm = this;
                axios.get('/configuracao/language')
                .then((response) => {
                    vm.config.linguagem = response.data;
                    Lang.setLocale(response.data);
                }).catch(e => {
                    console.log('Error', e);
                });
            }
        },
        watch: {
            'config.linguagem': function(value) {
                Lang.setLocale(value);
            }
        },
        filters: {
            trans: function (value) {
                if (!value) return '';
                return Lang.get(value);
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Faça uma pergunta em português no forum BR.

Comment: Pesquisei aqui e não tenho ideia qual biblioteca é essa (Lang.js). Você poderia especificar melhor? É uma biblioteca separada ou já vem como Laravel?

Comment: @fernandosavio Laravel ( https://github.com/rmariuzzo/Laravel-JS-Localization ) + Javascript ( https://github.com/rmariuzzo/lang.js )